# Reference request for 3-manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

I am asking a soft question.

I am planning to learn $3$-manifold using the book "Geometry and topology of three-manifolds" by William Thurston. I want to know how much of Riemannian geometry, Algebraic topology, Smooth manifolds, Complex Geometry do I need to learn $3$- manifold. Also, I am looking for references of $3$-manifolds which contain exercises as I noticed that  William Thurston's contain does not contain exercises.

Also, it will be very much appreciatable if you also advise on book recommendations of $3$-manifolds.

Please advise me. Thanking in advance.

Comment: I honestly recommend starting with a solid understanding of algebraic topology from Hatcher. This is standard background for almost every topic in topology.

Comment: take a look at https://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/cucei-maths/elementary-3-manifolds/

Comment: read also https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/15/5/401/268718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hatcher's books on Algebraic topology and 3-manifolds are recommended. As is Sveta  Katok's little book on Fuchsian groups.